# Focus lost after Fragment Change (ANDROID TV)

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

```
 public void changeFragment(String str) {


    SecFragment nextFrag = new SecFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("site", str);
    nextFrag.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), nextFrag)
            .commit();


}
```

This is my way to change a fragment in my Android TV app. But after changing I cant navigate in my 2nd Fragment. The focus gets lost.

I am actually using a copy of the Mainfragment just with other information, here is the 2ndFragment´s onactivitycreated method

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        site = bundle.getString("site");
    }

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    page = 1;

    list = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    prepareBackgroundManager();

    setupUIElements();
    loadRows1();
    setupEventListeners();
    Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(act.getResources(), R.drawable.splash);
    bm = BackgroundManager.getInstance(act);
    //bm.attach(act.getWindow());
    bm.setBitmap(mIcon);

    SetupVideos(site);

}
```

Both Fragments extend to the same BrowseFragment Class which is included in Android Studio

Answer (score -2):

You should use the addToBackStack() which would make it easier to navigate.

Comment: Already tried, with addtobackstack(null) but not working. I tried several ways to requestFocus on any view like the search button or the header or sth nothing working

Comment: I have not created an android TV app but if you are trying to navigate from one fragment to another fragment, you have to declare an interface and follow this documentation to do it. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Yes i think there is something like this in the Demo Project